# Why does Crookes want to "avoid inquiry" despite "pursuit of truth"?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Why does Crookes want to "avoid inquiry" despite "pursuit of truth"? 
It's a bit confusing.

He writes:

> "It argues ill for the boasted freedom of opinion among scientific men
>   that they have so long refused to institute a scientific investigation into
>   the existence and nature of facts asserted by so many competent and
>   credible witnesses, and which they are freely invited to examine when
>   and where they please. For my own part, I too much value the pursuit of
>   truth, and the discovery of any new fact in Nature, **to avoid inquiry**
>   because it appears to clash with prevailing opinions." In this spirit he
>   began his inquiry.

From [*The History of Spiritualism, Vol. I*](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html#chap11) by Arthur Conan Doyle.

Comment: As an aside, if "crooks" is someone's name, it should be capitalized.

Comment: The name is Crookes. He was a Fellow of the Royal Society in the 19th century.

Comment: Was he the Crookes who originated an electrical gas-discharge tube?

Comment: @Michael Harvey yes.

Answer (score 3):

He isn't saying he wants to avoid inquiry.

He says, "I too much value the pursuit of truth...to avoid inquiry". In today's speech we'd say, "I value the pursuit of truth too much to avoid inquiry".

So the meaning is that because he values the pursuit of truth, he **doesn't** want to avoid inquiry